# Fix dot - comma confusion, producing NaN while converting dataframe column dtype "object" to "float"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dtype

I have the following dataframe:

```
    ID customer Month   Amount
0   026         201707  31,65
1   026         201708  31,65
2   026         201709  31,65
3   026         201710  31,65
4   026         201711  31,65
```

where `Amount` is initially `object` type. I want to calculate sum and average amount for each ID. First I tried to convert `Amount` column from `object` into `float`:

```
df['Amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'], errors='coerce')
```

but I got `NaN` for all values in the `Amount` column:

```
    ID customer Month   Amount
0   026         201707  NaN
```

How to convert column object type into `float` with actual numbers, then aggregate the values for each customer (sum, mean)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) before `pd.to_numeric` to convert `,` in `.`Then you can use `groupby.agg`

```
agg_df = (df.assign(Amount = pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'].str.replace(',','.'),
                                           errors = 'coerce'))
            .groupby('ID').Amount.agg(['mean','sum']))
print(agg_df)
#if you want change the type of Amount previously
#df['Amount'] =pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'].str.replace(',','.'),errors = 'coerce')
#agg_df = df.groupby('ID').Amount.agg(['mean','sum']))

     mean    sum
ID              
0   31.65  31.65
1   31.65  31.65
2   31.65  31.65
3   31.65  31.65
4   31.65  31.65
```

---

**If you want aggregate to initial dataframe use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):**

```
groups = pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'].str.replace(',','.'),errors = 'coerce').groupby(df['ID'])
#if you want change the type of Amount previously
#df['Amount'] =pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'].str.replace(',','.'),errors = 'coerce')
#groups = df.groupby('ID')['Amount']
df['mean'] = groups.transform('mean')
df['sum'] = groups.transform('sum')
print(df)
   ID  customer   Month Amount   mean    sum  
0   0        26  201707  31,65  31.65  31.65  
1   1        26  201708  31,65  31.65  31.65  
2   2        26  201709  31,65  31.65  31.65  
3   3        26  201710  31,65  31.65  31.65  
4   4        26  201711  31,65  31.65  31.65
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler syntax available? No problem with the first part of the accepted answer:

```
df['Amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'].str.replace(',','.'))
```

Now about the grouping, pivot allows for a much simpler syntax:

```
pd.pivot_table(data = df,
               values = ['Amount'],
               index = ['ID customer'],
               aggfunc = [np.sum, np.mean])
```

Output:

```
                sum   mean
             Amount Amount
ID customer               
026          158.25  31.65
```